# php file upload to mysql .. [BLOB] or classic way ? which is good?

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

i'm not too expert in php .. so when i going to build a web app .. when i come to the upload files i use this way "and i really don't know is there anyone use it"

i put upload script and this upload script upload to folder .. not in database directly [BLOB]

when my client as example want add images he has use upload script first then

enter the image name with her type in field .. and use this code in while loop to show image

```
<img src="images/photo/<?php echo $rowfame['image_url'] ?>" alt="" />
```

so is this way good .. anyone use it ? or it is safe ?

really the main reason i asked this .. just to know is that expert way or it's just not

professional .. i need to use BLOB way .. or stick with this ?

Answer (score 0):

normally not all professional servers allow files to be uploaded, this is a blob way which i'm showing you with the use of php:
pass the file view form submit or ajax;

```
$fileName = $_FILES[$childTableColumnName]['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES[$childTableColumnName]['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES[$childTableColumnName]['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES[$childTableColumnName]['type'];
$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
```

And use $content in query for BLOB